# C2440 compilation error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I'm beginner. I'm using VS2008. In `file1.cpp` I'm calling the OALPAtoVA function present in `file2.c`. I'm getting `C2440`. I believe it is due to some confusion caused between C & C++ files during compilation.

**file1.cpp**

```
extern OMAP_MMCHS_REGS *m_pbRegisters;

m_pbRegisters = OALPAtoUA(AM33X_MMCHS1_REGS_PA);    //error at this line
```

**file_2.c**

```
VOID* OALPAtoVA(UINT32 pa, BOOL cached)
{
//some code
return va;
}
```

The error I get is,

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'OMAP_MMCHS_REGS *'
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Assuming the difference between `OALPAtoUA` and `OALPAtoVA` is just a typo in your question.</sub>

The problem is that unlike C, C++ doesn't provide an implicit conversion from `void*` to a different pointer type. So if your function returns a `void*`, you have to cast it explicitly:

```
m_pbRegisters = static_cast<OMAP_MMCHS_REGS*>(OALPAtoVA(AM33X_MMCHS1_REGS_PA));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved a huge amount of frustration!